# MudBlazor TextField is disabled but its validation works

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have a form that it is possible that some of the form elements (MudBlazor components), May be disabled.

The problem is that when the field is disabled I want no validation takes place because I send null instead of that field value.

But when the textfield is enabled (it is up to user to enable or disable the field using a checkbox) I want the validation occure.

But when the checkbox is unticked and the field is disabled, validation still works. I want when the field is disabled no validation occures. How to do this?

I use both fluent validation (for stringlength) and isrequired=true property at the same time on each field.

Comment: maybe just set the value of isrequired to be `isenabled` (the field in your code), and the validation to be `isenabled ? xxxx : null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a boolean property to your Formmodel for the disabled input.

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsNameDisabled {get; set;}
}
```

And use it to disable/enable the input

```
    <MudTextField 
        @bind-Value="model.Name"   
        Disabled="model.IsNameDisabled"                           
        For="@(() => model.Name)"
        Immediate="true"
        Label="Name" 
    />
```

Then you can include this property in fluent validation, so that Name only gets validated if the input is not disabled.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Name).Must(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).When(x => !x.IsNameDisabled)
```

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYQxFmFDcKBUXuDi)

Or if you want to set it inline you could

```
<MudTextField 
    @bind-Value="model.Name"   
    Disabled="model.IsNameDisabled"
    Required="!model.IsNameDisabled"                   
    For="@(() => model.Name)"
    Immediate="true"
    Label="Name" 
/>
```